# What is the property that says a button was selected in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i've been searching on internet for the property that says that a normal button was selected or not,  i think there must be one because when you click a button, it turns light blue, regardless the mouse is over it or not, and when you click another button, the previous button changes back to normal and the new clicked button is set light blue.

I  need it to know which button was just selected and draw a "resizing" square on it, and it gotta last as long as the button remains as the "selected one".

thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of button is it?  WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, other?

Comment: its a WinForms Button

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [Focused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.  For actually any `Control` it returns, whether it has input focus or not (so e.g. hitting `Enter` will cause the button to be clicked as well). Since it sounds like you want to be notified whenever that property changes, you should use the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events.

You can give a `Control` focus programmatically by calling `Focus`.

Comment: oh thanks, i feel stupid to realize it was such simple property. but helped me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do two things,
you can do it with the events: mouseEnter and MouseLeave,
this events launches when the mouse enters or leaves the visible control area,

also the focused(boolean) property gets and sets the "selected" element

one solution could be to:

```
private void onElementMousenter(blablabla,sender e); 
{
     e.Focused=true;
}
```

and assign the mouseEnter events in all controls to this one so the last element will be the "selected one" until you select another